# How to choose one vertex from a Maximal Independent Set found with maximal_ivs?

Tags: r, igraph

I found a list of Maximal independent sets using maximal_ivs.

```
max_set <- maximal_ivs(grafo)
```

How can I choose one of the Maximal Independent Sets, and then, choose one vertex from that set?
To get the name of the 3rd vertex in the 1st Set i tried:

```
vector<- unlist(max_set[1])
vector[3]$name
```

But it does give an error:
Error in vector[3]$name :

```
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Is there anyway to save each Maximal independent as a new vertex sequence?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create some sample data to make this reproducible.

```
set.seed(42)
g <- sample_gnp(100, 0.9)
V(g)$name <- paste0("Vertex", 1:100)

plot(g)
```

[image]

```
max_set <- maximal_ivs(g);

# Get 3rd set
v <- max_set[[3]]

# Get 2nd vertex
v[[2]]$name
[1] "Vertex36"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was what I needed!